# o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed //I saw the answers on this Web, but they dont help me

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My pom.xml
When I added  this dependencies - I had reloaded my project and run it.
When I debug it - It shows, that .web package is RED(not found) .
Maybe some dependencies are incorrect or their versions are not the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sk.Pipes</groupId>
    <artifactId>Pipes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And the running class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringClient {
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        SpringApplication.run(SpringClient.class);
    }
}
```

Pls help me, if you can. Or if you will find my mistake, pls write  how to correct it:)

That is the result.

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.


2022-04-19 19:05:20.839  WARN 16848 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:C:\Users\Xiaomi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.6\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration due to io/r2dbc/spi/ValidationDepth not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
2022-04-19 19:05:20.839  INFO 16848 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-19 19:05:20.854 ERROR 16848 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Comment: What is the package name of your class `SpringClient`

Comment: i think you are running in default package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your debug message has answer, @SpringBootApplication annotated class can't be in default package.

Create java package  and refactor this class to new package.

Comment: Thanks, that s solution. I have only created a new package in 'java' and refactor 'SpringClient' into it.